# Quick Edit very slow while saving

Tags: list-view, task-list, quick-edit

I have one site on my SharePoint 2013 server where the Quick Edit function of lists seems to be corrupt. 
For example when a bulk of data is copied from Excel to a list in Quick Edit view the first line is saved and on the second one SharePoint is not able to save the data. I checked all the data in the list and made some tests but nothing worked.

Today I got the issue that when the user of this site adds a task to a tasklist with main and subtasks, SharePoint doesn't save the data (which was inserted manually).
I also tested this issue. It seems that SharePoint is not able to save the data cause the "Working on it" screen doesn't disappears:

[image]

When I click on "**Leave anyway**" the data i inserted is in the list.

Has anybody an idea what the error could be or how to find the error?
Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Is it a performance issue in the WFE or the SQL Server?

Comment: May I know how much RAM is being used in your WFE and SQL Server? Is it a stand-alone or tier architecture? Are you working on production or development? This seems to be a performance issue.

Comment: I'll check this but I don't think that it could be a performance issue cause on other Sites these functions are working.

We are using 2 WFE with 32GB for each server.
The SQL Servers instance hast 60GB.

Answer (score 1):

This question is old, but no one ever answered it and the answer applies to SharePoint 2010, 2013, 2016 (and presumably 2019). The problem is most likely caused because of poor database maintenance practices. I recommend following the instructions in this blog ([SharePoint Database Maintenance Recommendations](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/premier-field-engineering/sharepoint-database-maintenance-recommendations/ba-p/323370)) to set up maintenance jobs to: check DB integrity, rebuild the index and update statistics.

Answer (score 0):

If you group list or library items in SharePoint Online, the quick edit option is disabled. remove the “Group By” selection by setting it to none. Change the View style to default: Changing view style to “Shaded”, “Newsletter” or something else disables Quick Edit.